# Firebase Phone auth is not verifying the OTP entered

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to integrate phone authentication system in my flutter app. But even when I enter a wrong OTP the user gets verified and enters into the next page.

I am using Dialog box to ask for OTP

````
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Enter sms Code'),
          content: TextFormField(
            controller: _smsController,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter OTP', icon: Icon(Icons.perm_phone_msg)),
            maxLength: 6,
            maxLengthEnforced: true,
          ),
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Login'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                onPressed: () {
                  _signInWithPhoneNumber(context);
                })
          ],
        );
      });```

```void _signInWithPhoneNumber(BuildContext context) async {
    final AuthCredential credential = await PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
    await _auth
        .signInWithCredential(credential)
        .then((FirebaseUser user) async {
      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => InfoScreen(_phoneNumberController.text)));
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e.message);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to get same of auth to verify a OTP of firebase admin as explained [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2018/10/flutter-login-registration-authentication-firebase.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have done the mistake with the `PhoneAuthProvider`

```
 final AuthCredential credential = await PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _smsController.text,
    );
```

Replace above code with this:

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance
        .signInWithPhoneNumber(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode)
        .then((user) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/homepage');
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
```

Using this you can verify the phone with code. For more details please visit [Here](https://tphangout.com/flutter-phone-authentication/)

Comment: But FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithPhoneNumber has been deprecated.

Comment: @mausomsaikia [Check This](https://github.com/gildaswise/flutter_phone_auth/blob/master/lib/routes/auth.dart)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add an onCompleteListener by changing the ".then(FirebaseUser ...)" to ".addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener(AuthResult res) {});"

The AuthResult object has a boolean "isSuccessful()" which you can check to make sure the user entered the correct code.

I assume that Firebase returns the FirebaseUser object no matter if the code actually matches.